# Pandas DataFrame adding header makes all value to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

I am new to Python.
I imported excel files with several tap. Then choose 1 tap and try to put Hierarchical column header but it generate all the value to NaN. Then if I change input from my excel data to Numpy array it works fine. I am not sure where I got wrong.

Below are codes.

```
fn= r'C:\Users\Yun\NN_FX\Bbg_Today_Data.xlsx'
a=df_dict['Output'].iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]]
a.head(15)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKgop.png)

```
arrays = [["KRW","KRW", "MYR","MYR"],["Date", "Price","Date", "Price"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
bb=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=arrays)
bb.head(15)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaov3.png)

But if I try with Numpy array. it works fine.

```
arrays = [["KRW","KRW", "MYR","MYR"],["Date", "Price","Date", "Price"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
aa=np.random.randn(15, 4)
bb=pd.DataFrame(aa,columns=arrays)
bb.head(15)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f43YD.png)

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: When passing a DataFrame to the DataFrame constructor with explicitly declared columns it attempts to locate the existing columns in the frame (it does not overwrite existing column names). Take a look at the small example `pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]}), columns=['c', 'a'])` or even with `dict` as in `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]}, columns=['c', 'a'])`. This does not happen with any collections which do not have indexes (which is why arrays, lists, etc behave as expected).

Comment: I see. Then is there anyway to get rid of exiting header?  or If I pass DataFrame to the DataFrame constructor with NOT explicitly declared columns, I can overwrite column names?(How to pass this way?)

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to set the column labels through the `columns` property

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'c:\test\Bbg_Today_Data.xlsx'
df_dict = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name=None)
a = df_dict['Output'].iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]]
a.columns = [["KRW", "KRW", "MYR", "MYR"], ["Date", "Price", "Date", "Price"]]
print(a.head(15))
```

Output:

```
                    KRW                               MYR           
                   Date        Price                 Date      Price
0   Updated at 09:13:39          NaN  Updated at 09:13:39        NaN
1              KRW=KFTC          NaN                 MYR=        NaN
2             Timestamp  Trade Close            Timestamp  Bid Close
3   2021-08-20 00:00:00       1179.6  2021-08-20 00:00:00      4.236
4   2021-08-19 00:00:00       1176.2  2021-08-19 00:00:00      4.237
5   2021-08-18 00:00:00         1168  2021-08-18 00:00:00      4.236
...
```

Comment: Working nicely. Thanks!